# How to give viewer access to change parameter of BigQuery from Data Studio

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I connected My dynamic Big Query with data studio where I take  @event_name as a single select parameter.

In Data studio edit mode I am able to change the @event_name parameter by selecting value from drop down and got the data based on selected value.
I want to give viewer to choose value for @event_name parameter, but in data studio view mode we don't access parameter directly.
I use this link  https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/data-source-parameters. For the reference.
I try to create report url same as in the above link but it don't change content of my table based on the parameter I passed.
Here is my link for the report https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/1ncaS95UZvEVoW36eXI9q5xXZ0DbtkW5N/page/CF5NB?params=%7B%22ds24.event_name%22:%22session_start%22%7D

Comment: I cant access the second link. What do you mean with  "I want to give viewer to choose value for @event_name parameter"?

Comment: For Second link i am passing dynamic parameter in Report Url

Answer (score -1):

Editing parameters in View Mode is not currently supported (May 2020). You can change the parameters in Edit Mode only.

Comment: By Passing Parameter name along with  value in report Url we can Edit it in view Mode. I added multiple report link which pass the value  of parameter in url and update the report data based on parameter value passed  on report url